# Comparing two strings in linux KSH script

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, string-comparison

I have two files: file1 and file2. Here is a sample of the files content:

```
<TG>
   <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
   <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
   <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-240" type="INT16" />
   ...
</TG>
```

I want to check if certain lines (those containing the string "entry name") in file1 exist in file2, and then if yes, compare if the two lines are identical or not.

I literally created file2 by copying file1, then I changed a few values. The problem is that comparing the two string variables does not return correct values. Although when displaying the two variables I can see they are identical, the result of the comparison gives that they are not. I am using Ksh. Here is my code:

```
while read p; do
    if [[ $p == *"entry name"* ]]; then
        PARAM_NAME=$(echo $p | cut -d '"' -f2)
        echo $PARAM_NAME
        PARAM_OLD=$(grep $PARAM_NAME file2)
        if [[ $PARAM_OLD == *"entry name"* ]]; then
            echo $PARAM_OLD
            echo $p
            if [ "$PARAM_OLD" = "$p" ]; then
                echo 'Identical values'
            else
                echo 'Different values'
            fi
        else
            echo "$PARAM_NAME does not exist in previous version file. Using default value"         
        fi
    fi
done <file1
```

I tried all possibilities for the parenthesis, equal signs and quotations ([], [[]], = , ==, "", '""', etc.)

Here is the output I am getting:

```
<entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
KEYNAME
<entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
<entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
Different values
<entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
KEYTYPE
<entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
<entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
Different values
<entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-24" type="INT16" />
TIMEZONE_OFFSET
<entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-240" type="INT16" />
<entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-24" type="INT16" />
Different values
```

Still I am getting that the strings are different! I would appreciate any explanation and help.

Comment: Including the complete script would be a smart move, we are a lazy bunch who like to copy-paste the problematic code in and test it first :)

Comment: for a given file, is an `entry name` value unique, eg, `entry name="KEYTYPE"` only shows up once in the file? also, which shell (bash, sh, ksh, ksh93) are you using?

Comment: Yes markp.. it only shows up once.. and I am using Ksh.

Comment: Have you considered using XML-aware tooling to transform your content into an easier-to-process form?

Comment: Use `xmllint --xpath` with the `document()` function.

Comment: ... ugh, `document()` is only found in XSLT's xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most recent/newer OSs have support for both ksh and ksh93.

With ksh93 we can use an associative array to limit ourselves to a single pass through each file.

First some sample data:

```
$ cat file1
<TG>
   <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
   <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
   <entry name="KEYATTRIB" val="" type="string" />
   <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-241" type="INT16" />
</TG>

$ cat file2
<TG>
   <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
   <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="stringX" />
   <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-240" type="INT16" />
</TG>
```

The ksh93 script:

```
$ cat my_comp
#!/bin/ksh93

unset      pline
typeset -A pline

# pull unique list of 'entry name' lines from file2 and store in our associative array pline[]:

egrep "entry name" file2 | sort -u | while read line
do
        # strip out the 'entry name' value

        x=${line#*\"}
        pname=${x%%\"*}

        # use the 'entry name' value as the index for our pline[] array

        pline[${pname}]=${line}
done

# for each unique 'entry name' line in file1, see if we have a match in file2 (aka our pline[] array):

egrep "entry name" file1 | sort -u | while read line
do
        # again, strip out the 'entry name' value

        x=${line#*\"}
        pname=${x%%\"*}

        # if pname does not exist in file2

        [ "${pline[${pname}]}" = '' ]                                                   && \
        echo "\npname = '${pname}' : Does not exist in file2. Using default value:"     && \
        echo "file1: ${line}"                                                           && \
        continue

        # if pname exists in file2 but line is different

        [ "${pline[${pname}]}" = "${line}" ]                            && \
        echo "\npname = '${pname}' : Identical values for pname"        && \
        echo "file1: ${line}"                                           && \
        echo "file2: ${pline[${pname}]}"                                && \
        continue

        # if pname exists in file2 and line is the same

        [ "${pline[${pname}]}" != "${line}" ]                           && \
        echo "\npname = '${pname}' : Different values for pname"        && \
        echo "file1: ${line}"                                           && \
        echo "file2: ${pline[${pname}]}"
done
```

Running the script against the sample files:

```
$ my_comp

pname = 'KEYATTRIB' : Does not exist in file2. Using default value:
file1: <entry name="KEYATTRIB" val="" type="string" />

pname = 'KEYNAME' : Identical values for pname
file1: <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
file2: <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />

pname = 'KEYTYPE' : Different values for pname
file1: <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
file2: <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="stringX" />

pname = 'TIMEZONE_OFFSET' : Different values for pname
file1: <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-241" type="INT16" />
file2: <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-240" type="INT16" />
```

---

Back to plain ol' basic ksh:

```
$ cat my_comp2
#!/bin/ksh

egrep "entry name" file1 | sort -u | while read line1
do
        x=${line1#*\"}
        pname=${x%%\"*}

        # see if we can find a matching line in file2; need to strip off leading
        # spaces in order to match with line1

        unset line2
        line2=$( egrep "entry name.*${pname}" file2 | sed 's/^ *//g' )

        # if pname does not exist in file2

        [ "${line2}" = '' ]                                                            && \
        echo "\npname = '${pname}' : Does not exist in file2. Using default value:"    && \
        echo "file1: ${line1}"                                                         && \
        continue

        # if pname exists in file2 but lines are different

        [ "${line2}" = "${line1}" ]                                     && \
        echo "\npname = '${pname}' : Identical values for pname"        && \
        echo "file1: ${line1}"                                          && \
        echo "file2: ${line2}"                                          && \
        continue

        # if pname exists in file2 and lines are the same

        [ "${line2}" != "${line1}" ]                                    && \
        echo "\npname = '${pname}' : Different values for pname"        && \
        echo "file1: ${line1}"                                          && \
        echo "file2: ${line2}"
done
```

Running the script against the sample files:

```
$ my_comp2

pname = 'KEYATTRIB' : Does not exist in file2. Using default value:
file1: <entry name="KEYATTRIB" val="" type="string" />

pname = 'KEYNAME' : Identical values for pname
file1: <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />
file2: <entry name="KEYNAME" val="" type="string" />

pname = 'KEYTYPE' : Different values for pname
file1: <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="string" />
file2: <entry name="KEYTYPE" val="" type="stringX" />

pname = 'TIMEZONE_OFFSET' : Different values for pname
file1: <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-241" type="INT16" />
file2: <entry name="TIMEZONE_OFFSET" val="-240" type="INT16" />
```

Comment: Great solution , except that I am not able to run ksh93, and I am getting a ./installScript.sh[195]: typeset: -A: unknown option error :(

Comment: Are you saying that ksh93 is not available on your linux dist? What do the following show: `ls -l /bin | egrep ksh` and `ls -l /usr/bin | egrep ksh`?  the error you're receiving is because ksh does not support 'A'ssociative arrays while ksh93 does; I'd be really surprised if your linux dist doesn't have ksh93

Comment: :-( Here is the output:
`# ls -l /bin | egrep ksh
-r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  444660 Feb 26  2016 ksh
-r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  444660 Feb 26  2016 rksh
# ls -l /usr/bin | egrep ksh
#`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a plain ol' basic ksh script; as you can see from the various answers ... lots of ways to slice-n-dice this ...

Answer (score 0):

You have just 1 = in your if statement, change it to two:

```
if [ "$PARAM_OLD" = "$p" ]; then
```

to:

```
if [ "$PARAM_OLD" == "$p" ]; then
```

Also (isn't the problem now, but might be your next problem), surround $PARAM_OLD with " in the following line:

```
if [[ $PARAM_OLD == *"entry name"* ]]; then
```

so it becomes:

```
if [[ "$PARAM_OLD" == *"entry name"* ]]; then
```

Comment: I used all possible combinations..
if [ "$PARAM_OLD" == "$p" ]; then
if [[ "$PARAM_OLD" == "$p" ]]; then
if [ "$PARAM_OLD" = "$p" ]; then
if [[ "$PARAM_OLD" = "$p" ]]; then

All of them are returning the same!

Comment: try comparing with grep:

echo "$PARAM_OLD" | grep "$p"

if it outputs anything use that to compare the string instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### Transforming from XML to Tab-Separated Key/Value Pairs

The following will transform your content into tab-separate key-value form:

```
xml_to_tsv() {
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//entry[@name]' -v ./@name -o $'\t' -v ./@value -n
}
```

#### Extracting Unique Lines From Each

Thus, if you want to compare your two streams, the following will emit only lines unique to the first file:

```
comm -23 <(xml_to_tsv <one.xml | sort) <(xml_to_tsv <two.xml | sort)
```

...and the following will emit only lines unique to the second:

```
comm -13 <(xml_to_tsv <one.xml | sort) <(xml_to_tsv <two.xml | sort)
```

---

#### Doing The Same, Without XMLStarlet

If you don't have XMLStarlet installed, you can generate an XSLT template to perform the same operation. Thus, if you have the following file as `extract_entries.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//entry[@name]">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@value"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...you could use the following `xml_to_tsv` implementation on systems that don't have XMLStarlet at all:

```
xml_to_tsv() {
  xsltproc extract_entries.xslt -
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a minimal linux installation, and I have no xml tools at all..

Answer (score 0):

Using the following two data files and one transform file:

file1.xml:

```xml
<TG>
  <entry name="common" value="foo"/>
  <entry name="changed" value="bar"/>
  <entry name="unique1" val="qux"/>
</TG>
```

file2.xml:

```xml
<TG>
  <entry name="common" value="foo"/>
  <entry name="changed" value="bar"/>
  <entry name="unique2" val="quux"/>
</TG>
```

transform.xslt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- To be passed with xsltproc's stringparam argument -->
  <xsl:param name="other"/>
  <!-- Convenience aliases -->
  <xsl:variable name="file1" select="/"/>
  <xsl:variable name="file2" select="document($other)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
      <common_entries>
        <xsl:for-each select="$file1/TG/entry[@name]">
          <xsl:variable name="node1" select="."/>
          <xsl:variable name="node2" select="$file2/TG/entry[@name=$node1/@name]"/>
          <!-- xpath 1.0, the only version people use, lacks the deep-equal() function -->
          <xsl:if test="$node1/@value = $node2/@value">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$node1"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </common_entries>
      <changed_entries>
        <xsl:for-each select="$file1/TG/entry[@name]">
          <xsl:variable name="node1" select="."/>
          <xsl:variable name="node2" select="$file2/TG/entry[@name=$node1/@name]"/>
          <xsl:if test="$node1/@value != $node2/@value">
            <diff>
              <old>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$node1"/>
              </old>
              <new>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$node2"/>
              </new>
            </diff>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </changed_entries>
      <unique1_entries>
        <xsl:for-each select="$file1/TG/entry[not(@name=$file2/TG/entry/@name)]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </unique1_entries>
      <unique2_entries>
        <xsl:for-each select="$file2/TG/entry[not(@name=$file1/TG/entry/@name)]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </unique2_entries>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Standard identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then running `xsltproc --stringparam other file2.xml transform.xslt file1.xml` will produce:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
  <common_entries>
    <entry name="common" value="foo"/>
  </common_entries>
  <changed_entries>
    <diff>
      <old>
        <entry name="changed" value="bar"/>
      </old>
      <new>
        <entry name="changed" value="baz"/>
      </new>
    </diff>
  </changed_entries>
  <unique1_entries>
    <entry name="unique1" val="qux"/>
  </unique1_entries>
  <unique2_entries>
    <entry name="unique2" val="quux"/>
  </unique2_entries>
</results>
```